# How to create a symlink link

Tags: 14.04, permissions, mount, symbolic-link

I would like to create a symlink link for my

1. Web-files
2. Mysql-files
3. Email-files

Right now the Web-files are stored in following location

```
/var/www/html
```

Mysql-files

```
/var/lib/mysql
```

Email-files

```
/var/vmail
```

And i would like to create a symlink to the following location

I.E

```
/var/www/html to /files/Web-files
/var/lib/mysql to /files/Mysql-files
/var/vmail to /files/Email-files
```

Something like orphan symlink link

I.e all the data need to accessed from /files only

And when i access /var/www/html i should get /var/www/html: No such file or directory

Also i should retain current permission of that directory too

I tired all the tutorials available in ubuntu community & web but it doesn't help me to achieve the result

Kindly guide me to achieve this

~thanks

Comment: It's impossible (afaik) to make a symlink to a real location such that the real location behaves as if it no longer exists

Comment: only the files is the real location so my syntax for creating symlink is sudo ln -sv /var/www/html /files/Web-files where "Web-files" doesn't exists only /files exists. but after creating the symlink it creates shortcut so i can able to same data from /var/www/html & /files/Web-files but what i want to achieve is that i should able to access the data only from /files/Web-files & when i access /var/www/html i should get No such file or directory error. i hope now you can understand what i am trying achieve. saw a concept of orphan symlink but i am unable to make it work

Comment: I understand, i'm saying it's impossible as far as I know. I think an orphan symlink is a *broken* symlink

Comment: thanks for your valuable input @Zanna but it is achievable as far as i know as i have seen this working it is that i don't have a clue what procedure has been followed to achieve this

Comment: Why don't you just move the directories to `/files` as you say you do not need them in the original place....